# Cross-browser and cross-platform click on a document

Tags: javascript, jquery

How make a cross-browser and cross-platform click on a document? I have tryed:

```
        var clickEvent = function (e) {
            console.log(123);
        };

        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.onclick = clickEvent;
        document.addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
        window.addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
        body.addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
```

But in different browsers it works few times. How to make it work only once?

Comment: why are you binding 3 click events?

Comment: you could use any one of the click

Comment: i founded that "solution" in google, for browsers such as Safari on iPhone

Answer (score 0):

The best one to use is

```
document.addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
```

Remove the other ones. It's running many times because you handle the click event on multiple elements (`window`, `document` and `document.body`). They all trigger because all clicks inside the viewport trigger click events on those objects. Your code should look like this:

```
var clickEvent = function (e) {
    console.log(123);
};

document.addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want maximum compatibility, use `onclick`:

```
var clickEvent = function (e) {
    console.log(123);
};
document.onclick = clickEvent;
```

Comment: I did it at first, but it seems to doesn`t work in few browsers on some devices..

Comment: @FeR-S It should work on all platforms. Where does it not work?

Comment: @FeR-S I've added a more compatible method.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a universal solution for all platforms and browsers?

Comment: @FeR-S Yes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Answer (score 0):

There could be issue with IE browsers with `addEventListener()` as some of the old internet explorer browsers doesn't have implementation of it but it has `attachEvent`. So, you might look to bind it too and app browsing is not limited to desktop devices only. There might be the user is on mobile devices so you might make use of `touch` events like `touchstart/touchend` etc. :

```js
var clickEvent = function(e) {
  console.log(itHas, 123);
};
var body = document.body; // get the document's body
var itHas = document.implementation.hasFeature(addEventListener), // check for the
docClick, //                                                feature implementation. 
ev = navigator.userAgent.indexOf(/mobi/g) !== -1 ? "touchstart" : "click";
// above will use an event based on user agent like for mobile it will use touch event
// and for desktop/laptops click event.
if(itHas){
  docClick = body.addEventListener;
}else{
  docClick = body.attachEvent;
}
docClick(ev, clickEvent);
```

Comment: What is for this row on your example `var body = document.body;` ?

Comment: `document.body` is the shortest way to target body of a document.

Comment: @FeR-S Ahh! i get it. just replaced the document with body var in the if/else conditions.

Comment: What is difference beetwen **document** and **document.body**? What is the best solution? Can i use just **document.addEventListener** ?

Comment: Yes! you can use `document.addEventListener` and it is just a slight slower than document because it has to find body in the document.

Comment: I`ve tryed your solution, but it doesnt work in Safari on iPhone and in OperaMini, in contrast to the **document.onclick = clickEvent;** ? Whats the reason?